# How to rearrange the div elements for mobile by using CSS(Preferred) or Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I just want to know how to rearrange the div element for mobile by using CSS. Please check the below images to mentioned what i exactly needed.

**For Desktop Look like Below**

[image]

**But In Mobile View,** I need to interchange the positions like below.

[image]

I checked it but i didn't get any solution for that, can you help me in that situation ?
**I used Bootstrap v3.3.7**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-push-8">
      <div class="border">
       Content B
       <hr/>
       <p>
       I think most people would (at first) assume that the desktop views would be rendered in normal order and that the pushing and pulling are done on the mobile views. Once you realize that the complete opposite is true, you begin to understand how to layout your columns in the correct order, and the correct classes that need to be used.

Conclusion
The two statements below summarize the functionality of the push and pull classes and should give you the full understanding of how they work, and how they should be used.

col-vp-push-x = push the column to the right by x number of columns, starting from where the column would normally render (position: relative), on a vp or larger view-port.

col-vp-pull-x = pull the column to the left by x number of columns, starting from where the column would normally render (position: relative), on a vp or larger view-port.

vp = xs, sm, md, or lg (minimum viewport)

x = 1 thru 12 (number of columns)
       </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-pull-4">
      <div class="border">
        Content A
        <hr/>
         <p>
       I think most people would (at first) assume that the desktop views would be rendered in normal order and that the pushing and pulling are done on the mobile views. Once you realize that the complete opposite is true, you begin to understand how to layout your columns in the correct order, and the correct classes that need to be used.

       </p>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/ravinthranath/b2Lfcqua/ and https://jsfiddle.net/ravinthranath/4tw2p4j9/**

Comment: You are right @paulie_d, i tried the situation in js fiddle i forgot to add it here, i apologize for that and also i know it's not code writing service. Please check my profile so that you can know about me.

Answer (score 0):

Im sure there is an easier way but just messing around I made this.
I'm sure if you did more research you could find a css only answer.

Edited:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("m1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("3").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("m2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("1").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("m3").innerHTML = document.getElementById("4").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("m4").innerHTML = document.getElementById("2").innerHTML;
}, false);
```

```css
.card {
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.left {float: left;width:50%;overflow:hidden;}
.right {float: left;width:50%;overflow:hidden;}
.mobile {display: none;}
input {padding: 8px;}

.left .card:nth-child(1) {color: blue;}
.left .card:nth-child(2){color: green;}
.right .card:nth-child(1) {color: orange;}
.right .card:nth-child(2) {color: red;}

.card:nth-child(1) {color: orange;}
.card:nth-child(2) {color: blue;}
.card:nth-child(3) {color: red;}
.card:nth-child(4) {color: green;}
p {color:black!important;}

@media screen and (max-width: 601px) {
  .left {display:none;}
  .right {display:none;}
  .mobile {display:block;}
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <div id="1" class="card">
    <h2>Col-md-8</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ultrices mattis urna, nec venenatis lectus dignissim aliquet. Nulla quis sodales metus. Nulla in nunc rhoncus, finibus mauris quis, mattis odio. Vestibulum scelerisque, augue eget ornare efficitur, purus metus hendrerit nibh, sed convallis mauris tortor eget odio. Phasellus ut enim eu nunc tincidunt euismod.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="2" class="card">
    <h2>Col-md-8</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ultrices mattis urna, nec venenatis lectus dignissim aliquet. Nulla quis sodales metus. Nulla in nunc rhoncus, finibus mauris quis, mattis odio. Vestibulum scelerisque, augue eget ornare efficitur, purus metus hendrerit nibh, sed convallis mauris tortor eget odio. Phasellus ut enim eu nunc tincidunt euismod. Ut placerat ante fermentum nisi ornare pharetra. Praesent rhoncus metus neque, ut auctor sapien imperdiet et. Curabitur lacinia nisi non mi commodo, suscipit iaculis nibh cursus. Phasellus in tellus augue. Nam vel magna sodales lorem imperdiet fringilla vitae ac dolor. Nam at velit lacus. Quisque mollis convallis odio, et fermentum orci auctor vitae. Integer rhoncus ultricies dictum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <div id="3" class="card">
    <h2>Col-md-4</h2>
    <input placeholder="Search" type="text">
  </div>
  <div id="4" class="card">
    <h2>Col-md-4</h2>
    <img src="http://cdn.tutorialzine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/50-useful-libraries-resources-responsive-design2.jpg" style="width: 100%;" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mobile">
  <div id="m1" class="card"></div>
  <div id="m2" class="card"></div>
  <div id="m3" class="card"></div>
  <div id="m4" class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You @rick-sibley but in responsive it doesn't work as i expected.

Comment: @Ravi Delixan, I changed the code. Is that any better. Like I said its probably not the best way to get it done.

Comment: Ok @RaviDelixan , I edited it again, I'm pretty sure that should do you good until someone leaves a better answer.

Comment: Very useful information you provided to me @rick-sibley, I just preferred CSS.

Comment: It is a simple one, no need for JS. It is making so complected. And of course easy to maintain. Let's Say in future you need some other element in same manner, Again we have add the script for that. Hence i will not prefer your suggestion.

Comment: Left a comment on your post.